# Python Error When creating a .py file from a .ui file (from Qt designer)

Tags: python, qt, user-interface

I tried a lot of technics but nothing work, I want to convert my .ui file to a .py file, using the pyuic4 in cmd, but the result is :
    from PyQt4 import QtCore
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 [...] is not a valid Win32 application

I'm using a 64bits system with python27 and "PyQt4-4.11.4-gpl-Py2.7-Qt4.8.7-x64.exe" from Riverbank, I think it's because I install a 64bits version but i'm not sure.
If someone could have an idea, it could be awesome ! :)

Comment: Is your python27 32bit? They all need to match.

Comment: yes, it was, but I only uninstall everythings and, reinstall all python components, Qt too, and now it's working, I think it's because my version of Qt was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try PYQT 3. Version 4 has some bugs in it